# MS Access database size huge with no data?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an MS access DB with 35 linked tables, a few queries and another 35 reports.

The database has no physical tables in it as all data for its tables are coming from the linked back-end MS Access database. The problem now is, the front-end database size is above 1 GB. How and why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Does Compact & Repair cure the problem?

Comment: *"no physical tables in it"* That is not possible.  It must include at least system tables.  And other tables could be hidden.  Ask Access how many tables are present by running this statement in the Immediate window: `Debug.Print CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count`

Comment: Thank you... I will check that...

Answer (score 1):

First, please try HansUp's suggestion.

But, if that doesn't shrink it as much as you expect, try this:

Make a file called `decompile.bat`. In it, put the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\Your\Path\To\YourFrontEnd.accdb" /nostartup/decompile
```

Edit the paths to suit. Put this batch file in the same directory as your front-end.

To use:

1. Run `decompile.bat` by double-clicking on it in Windows Explorer
2. In Access:

   - Hit Alt-F11 to go to the Visual Basic Editor
   - Click Debug, then Compile
   - Save, then exit the Visual Basic Editor
   - In the main Access window, click Database Tools, Compact and Repair Database
3. When finished, exit Access

You should notice that your front-end is dramatically smaller.

Comment: Kismert - I did exactly like what you suggested but the size is still the same...more than 1 GB.. I also tried the method by HansUp but I don't know how to run that command after pasting it in immediate window.

Comment: Arus - Hit Ctrl-G, paste the command line in, and hit enter. That worked for me. Regarding your larger issue: 1) Make a blank database. 2) In Access, click External Data, Access. 3) In the Get External Data dialog, import everything from the old database into the new. 4) Tell me if this fixes the problem.

Comment: I've had databases do this. A large application (with nearly all the data in a SQL-Server database) with 20 forms, 20 reports, 20 modules is 10MB large. Occasionally after editing something trivial the size becomes 80MB. Backups, decompile, Compact & Repair -- nothing shrinks it. Create a new database and copy everything into it -- back to 20MB. Slightly annoying, guess I'm not the only one encountering this.

Comment: @gordonprince: Try to find a pattern: does the database bloat when a certain form or report is touched? This might be naming collision -- you might have two global objects (forms, reports, public functions/subs) with the same name

Comment: It was enough doing `In the main Access window, click Database Tools, Compact and Repair Database`

Answer (score 1):

That's a very late addition but I wonder why didn't anyone point at the cause of the proplem! Microsoft says the cause is:

> If you do not release a recordset's memory each time that you loop
> through the recordset code, DAO may recompile, using more memory and
> increasing the size of the database.

And the solution:

> Use the Close method of the Recordset object to explicitly close the
> recordset's memory when you no longer need the recordset. If the
> database has increased in size because you did not use the Close
> method of the Recordset object, you can reduce the size of the
> database by running the Compact and Repair utility (on the Tools
> menu).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/prevent-database-bloat-dao

I've used the "Compact and repair tool" from the "Database tools" ribbon once and it did reduced the size of -an almost empty- database from 2.0 GB (Max. Size) to just 3.41 MB!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this. We use access databases to store project data. For the most part they stay less than a megabyte. Then I was getting issues from a client that storage cost was going up on a server because some databases were growing to the tens and hundreds of megabytes. So I search my stuff and found a database at a gig!

I'm using Office 7, and I'm pretty sure it is still in 365.

**Solution:**

From the Office button in access, (upper left). Go to Manage -> Backup Database. For me, it copied that 1 gig database to a 720k database. And, of course, it opened fine and all the data was there. I found that *Compact and Repair* did not come anywhere close to the results of *backup*

I don't know why Microsoft lets this occur, I could not find a reasonable explanation for it.